# Unwanted javascript NODE_ENV headerline in Grails asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, grails

When running a Grails 4 application using 'grails run-app' every javascript file provided by the webserver is starting with the line:

```
var process = process || {env: {NODE_ENV: "development"}};
```

This line is not part of the javascript source code and is probably generated by the asset-pipeline plugin. This confuses the hell out of my development environments (both intellij and VSCode) and ruins breakpoint handling.

Does anybody know how i can avoid 'grails run-app' generating this header line?

Some version information:

- Grails 4.0.5
- asset-pipeline-grails:3.2.4
- java-version 11.0.9.

I have generated the 'helloworld' application using 'grails create-app' and run it without modifying anything using 'grails run-app'. Even now every serviced javascript file has the header line.

Comment: OK, the headerline is generated by the JsNodeInjectProcessor asset-pipeline-core package, which is attached by asset.pipeline.JsEs6AssetFile, included in META-INF/asset.specs. I have found no documentation where i can select the pipeline (asset.pipeline.JsAssetFile iso asset.pipeline.JsEs6AssetFile). Grails magic!

Comment: " I have found no documentation where i can select the pipeline"- Those docs are available at http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#extending.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown that manual describes how to write your own pipeline components. I could find nothing about how to select specific components. I should have been more clear about that. The manual you point to was invaluable for writing the component mentioned in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you need to overwrite the default asset pipeline with your own pipeline. Your own pipeline will leave out the JsNodeInjectProcessor which is the culprit.

Defining your own pipeline involves the following steps:

- modify your build.gradle so all asset-pipeline modules are available     at compile time
- create MyJsAssetFile based on JsAssertFile from    the -core package. From the processors variable, leave out    JsNodeInjectProcessor.
- create a file    main/resources/META-INF/asset-pipeline/asset.specs, leaving out asset.pipeline.JsAssetFile and replacing it by MyJsAssetFile

Doing this will result in javascript files without the header line, and most importantly my Intellij IDE being able to debug my javascript logic embedded in my grails application.

Comment: Three years later and i was bitten again by the same bug. This solution (which took me three hours to remember ;)) solved it again. I do not understand why it has no upvotes. I guess nobody uses Intellij/Grails any more ;)